# IIS Local ошибка 404 или 400

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis

Не могу уже очень длительное время запустить сайт (помечен черным) в ЛОКАЛЬНОЙ СЕТИ из-за ошибок

1. На порту 81 выдает HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
2. На порту 80 выдает HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

А если к примеру пробовать запустить Default Web Site в локальной сети все работает отлично, да и запуск созданного сайта (помечен черным) но уже через "Диспетчере служб IIS" на любом порту также превосходно работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно убрать имя узла, тогда запросы будут направляться на ip хоста